# PostgreSQL - creating database from a template database

Tags: postgresql

If I create a database `foo` that:

1. Has initial data
2. Loads custom stored procedures
3. Loads and uses an external library

If I create a database `foobar` like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE foobar WITH ENCODING 'UTF8' TEMPLATE foo;
```

Will database `foobar` have:

1. The same data that foo was initialised with
2. The same custom stored procedures loaded by `foo`
3. The ability to use the shared library loaded in `foo`

**[[Addendum]]**

I have written several C library extensions which are loaded as shared libraries in the database I am using as a template. My main concern is whether these libraries will be also loaded by subsequent databases based on the template.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you try yourself?..

```
t=# create database foo;
CREATE DATABASE
Time: 426.799 ms
t=# \c foo
You are now connected to database "foo" as user "postgres".
```

data:

```
foo=# create table b(i int);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 3.794 ms
foo=# insert into b select 43;
INSERT 0 1
Time: 13.608 ms
```

fn():

```
foo=# create function a() returns int as $$select 42;$$ language sql;
CREATE FUNCTION
Time: 1.548 ms
```

extension:

```
foo=# create extension pg_stat_statements;
CREATE EXTENSION
Time: 4.275 ms
```

using template:

```
foo=# create database boo template foo;
CREATE DATABASE
Time: 640.328 ms
foo=# \c boo
You are now connected to database "boo" as user "postgres".
```

data is there:

```
boo=# select count(1) from b;
 count
-------
     1
(1 row)

Time: 1.569 ms
```

extension is usable:

```
boo=# select count(1) from pg_stat_statements;
 count
-------
  4927
(1 row)

Time: 1023.658 ms
```

fn() returns same result:

```
boo=# select a();
 a
----
 42
(1 row)

Time: 0.399 ms
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My PG foo is not quite up to par; I suppose, I could try with a "toy" example like the one you posted. My template database loads a lot of C extensions - and this was my main concern - so before I accept your answer, could you please confirm if C extensions loaded in the template will be available in databases based on the template db?

Comment: in my turn I have no experience with C extension, and no toy env to try it - sorry :) But I assume it should work. anyway - you can create a dummy db and create one extension there to see if i successfully goes to another db on creation with template - if it works, you can expect (up to some level) others should do as well

Comment: actually after re-reading your answer, I realise that I don't understand parts of it. what is the purpose of the statement `select count(1) from pg_stat_statements;` and what does the result signify? Does it mean that the functions created in database `foo` are available in database `boo`?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli I elaborated the answer to be more readable - pg_stat_statements is extension - you cant select from `pg_stat_statements` unless you create it - so it was an example of extension

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the database foo as a template database.

> ALTER DATABASE foo  IS_TEMPLATE true ;

Then you can use it to create new databases

> CREATE DATABASE foobar TEMPLATE foo;

Comment: ```istemplate
If true, then this database can be cloned by any user with CREATEDB privileges; if false (the default), then only superusers or the owner of the database can clone it.```